# python3 cidr from dotted notation

Tags: python, ip, subnet, cidr

I am trying to convert an IP address into cidr notation from standard dotted.
The error I receive indicated I need to change my sys.argv into a string, but I cannot find a way to convert it to a string.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
import json
import string
import iptools
import os.path
import requests
import subprocess
import socket,struct

from time import gmtime, strftime

label = sys.argv[1]
domain = sys.argv[2]
ipv4 = sys.argv[3]
ipv6 = sys.argv[4]

cidr = socket.inet_aton(ipv4)
cidr.decode('utf-8')

fd = open( domain+".external", 'w')
fd.write(domain+".              IN TXT  \"v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:"+cidr+" -all\"\n")
```

cli:

```
[\u@yoda:/usr/local/etc/namedb] # python3.4 makecustdomain.py jolly santa.com 108.61.190.64 2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makecustdomain.py", line 23, in <module>
    fd.write(domain+".              IN TXT  \"v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:"+socket.inet_aton(ipv4)+" -all\"\n")
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

how do I convert an IP address from sys.argv into cidr notation?

Comment: The code you gave does not match up with the error message.

Comment: Can you give us an example of sample input and expected output.

Comment: @pajaja  I posted the exact command line entry(argv) used. I apologize for the lame FreeBSD command line, but the info is there. and the output is cidr notation  http://infocenter.guardiandigital.com/manuals/IDDS/node9.html  1.2.3.4/24

Comment: @MattDMo you want the other 50 lines of comments and junk? The error is crystal clear, the solution however is not.  No other lines effect that error.

Comment: here's the rest  https://bpaste.net/show/d0380698ea2d

Comment: I know what cidr notation is but I still don't know what output do you expect. You're not passing the subnet mask anywhere so the only correct answer to your example would be 108.61.190.64/32.

Comment: @pajaja yes, that's the intended format.

Comment: @pajaja no where in no sample code to they add the subnetmask. It made no flippin sense to me either. so I have no friggin clue where to add 255.255.255.0